RedHat DeveloperHub Error with integration with Microsoft Entra ID
Im configuring RHDH in CRC and in dev in my job
In my local, im facing this issue
Login failed; caused by Error: Sign in failed: User not found in the RHDH software catalog. Verify that users/groups are synchronized to the software catalog. For non-production environments, manually provision the user or disable the user provisioning requirement. Refer to the RHDH Authentication documentation for further details.
And in my job is "Login Failed caused by PopupClosedError: Login Failed, popup was closed"
Im using this configMap
    app:
  baseUrl: https://DOMAIN.apps-crc.testing/
backend:
  baseUrl: https://DOMAIN.apps-crc.testing/
auth:
  environment: production
  providers:
    microsoft:
      production:
        clientId: ${AUTH_AZURE_CLIENT_ID}
        clientSecret: ${AUTH_AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET}
        tenantId: ${AUTH_AZURE_TENANT_ID}
        domainHint: ${AUTH_AZURE_TENANT_ID}
        callbackUrl: https://DOMAIN.apps-crc.testing/api/auth/microsoft/handler/frame
        baseUrl: https://DOMAIN.apps-crc.testing/
        signIn:
          resolver: 
            type: custom
            options:
              userIdAnnotation: "microsoft.com/email"
            allowedDomains:
              - microsoft.org
        additionalScopes:
          - Mail.Send
signInPage: microsoft
dangerouslyAllowSignInWithoutUserInCatalog: false
catalog:
  providers:
    microsoftGraphOrg:
      providerId:
        authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/
        target: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0
        tenantId: ${AUTH_AZURE_TENANT_ID}
        clientId: ${AUTH_AZURE_CLIENT_ID}
        clientSecret: ${AUTH_AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET}
        user:
          filter: accountEnabled eq true


Im using the secrets correctly and in Redirect URL in Azure im using this permissions and 
The documentatios is not much and i dont know how to add user or groups in catalog

To resolve the "User not found in the RHDH software catalog" issue, you need to either synchronize users/groups with the catalog or manually provision them. For the "PopupClosedError," ensure that your redirect URI and authentication settings in Azure AD are correctly configured, and check if pop-up blockers are interfering.
